# Do I have a chance to postdoc without any papers?

Tags: postdocs, job-search

I finished my Ph.D. in Plant Biology almost a year ago, and I am very interested in continuing my research in a postdoctoral fellowship. But, unfortunately, due to some problems I encountered during my Ph.D,  I have not published any paper yet.

1. Do I have a chance for any postdoc position?
2. Or Should I attend another Ph.D. program and do I have any chance to
   get a second Ph.D. position?
3. Is it possible to text the professors directly or to tell them that
   I can support myself for a trial period in your laboratory?
4. If yes, how should I tell them?

I will highly appreciate any kind of suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your resume and how other researchers publish in your field. If it is normal that PhD students in your field do not publish so much, and it is not expected of them to publish so many papers, then you do not miss so much in this regard.

But you should seek what other factors are important for the supervisor you are going to work with or the department you are joining. It is very frequent that it is expected from post-docs to show they can manage scientific projects, write proposals, search for some funding and resources, shape collaborations, coach a few students in their teams, write research and educational publications, etc.

Some job offers need one or more of the above skills. But do not underestimate the scientific knowledge. Some supervisors find an applicant who shows that they know a very specific methodology which can open many research opportunities in the future, so without seeking for traditional factors, they decide to hire them.

By the way, I suggest that you do not pre-judge your resume and give yourself a chance to submit your application. You will get a more clear understanding on how you should shape your resume to fit in such job offers. After that and with sufficient discussions with your PhD supervisors, then you decide what your resume lacks. Maybe you decide to publish a few papers out of your PhD research project and search for more relevant post-doc positions. Your previous supervisors have much better understanding on how you can improve your resume, find positions that fit your skills, what parts you need to work more on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view (physics): I wouldn't hire a postdoc without any publications, *unless* they had a very strong recommendation letter from their supervisor (whom I would need to know well enough to judge their trustworthiness), and there would be a good reason why there were no publications.

Answer (score 0):

In our field (Computer Engineering), Ph.D. students are *required* to have some publications, in order to earn their PhD title (the number of required publications depend on the university).

As such, post-doc positions always require candidates with some publications.

Comment: Is this a rule specific to your field (e.g., there are other STEM fields at your university that don't require this?) or a country/university standard?

Comment: @Kimball,  Fulvio's profile says that he is in "Turin, Italy". I guess that, perhaps, his answer could be for Italian universities. (Just a guess).

Comment: I think is depends a lot on the country (and in some cases on the "selectivity" of the University). My experience is mainly for the Computer Engineering field, both in Italy and in Europe.
I don't know if the practice also extends to the wider STEM fields.